# Are there any Visual Studio add-ins for true 'smart tabs'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins

'Smart Tabs' concept allows to automatically insert tab character for block indentation and space characters for in-block formatting. It's described [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs). Unfortunately, Visual Studio's 'smart tabs' option in text editor settings just indents text on enter press. Same name, completely different and near useless thing :). So, maybe someone knows of a visual studio addin that can change how 'tab' key work so it will insert tab characters and space characters according to rules mentioned above? Any hints are welcome.

Update: I need it for C++. According to comments, ReSharper can do something like this, but only for Basic and C#.

Comment: There are also [elastic tabstops](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137290/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-elastic-tabstops)... Not what you're after, but relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no one comes up with an "as-you-type" utility, then [Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) with its `convert-tabs` and `indent=tab` options will reformat code after-the-fact.

Comment: More recently, there's also an option to use [AStyle Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02?SRC=VSIDE):
http://code.google.com/p/astyle-extension/

Comment: @Matt, yes, and it can be installed right from Visual Studio 2010/2012 via the NuGet Package Manager using the menu item `Tools, Extensions and Updates...`.

Answer (score 3):

I have mapped the tab-button to Edit.FormatSelection in Visual Studio to achieve this and it works very well for me. I have also remapped the normal functionality of tab so that I still can access them (Edit.InsertTab and Edit.TabLeft).

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this pretty well, and is highly configurable.

Comment: Does it support any language (i'm interested in C++ and JavaScript) or only Visual Basic and C#?

Comment: That should be ReSharper. (Your link is right but the link text says ReShaper).

Comment: @Eye of Hell: Yes, it only supports C# and VB.NET for smart tabs.

Comment: Updated my question and mentioned C++ :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)?

It's been a while since I used it (back on VC++ 6.0!), and I can't see a mention of "Smart Tabs" on the home page, but it might be there somewhere.

Comment: I have licensed version of latest Visual Assist X installed. No options for tabs :(.